# Why are my comments no longer showing up on my Stack Exchange profile?

Tags: bug, comments, stackexchange.com, network-profile

I've made several comments on multiple Stack Exchange sites over the past week, but according to [my Stack Exchange profile](https://stackexchange.com/users/85546/blueraja-danny-pflughoeft?tab=activity), I haven't made any at all.  They do however show up on the "activity" page of the [individual](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/2578/blueraja-danny-pflughoeft?tab=activity) [sites](https://stackoverflow.com/users/238419/blueraja-danny-pflughoeft?tab=activity).  Is this a bug?

Comment: @BlueRaja Hmm. Interesting. Yeah, I see you have recent comments on SO, but they don't show up on the SE profile page.

Comment: Interestingly, all the comments I've made on sites other than Meta are also not appearing past June 28...

Comment: There was a leap second on Jun 30th. Maybe that caused it? Especially if you look at the fact that the SE.com data is cached for ~a day--which means that Jun 30th may have been borked by the leap second, and the cache was at Jun 28th at the time

Comment: I flagged something and didn't see neither the pending flag, nor the helpful mark. I almost flag twice because this

Comment: Looks like they update the network activity using some kind of a job that stopped working at June 28 - I bet a dev will pop here soon and fix this. :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

We're beginning to make some long-term changes to our code base to completely remove Linq2SQL, unfortunately the aggregation event hook that relays comment creation and deletion to the central network database was in a place specific to `.SubmitChanges()`.

I've hooked aggregation up to our new POCO version (inserts/deletes via dapper) and it will start aggregating after the build rolling out now.  The previous history will need a comment backfill at the network level, I'll see if we can't kick that off sometime before the weekend's over.

Comment: Completely removing Linq2SQL!? Some of us (like myself) are using it solely on Stackoverflow's recommendation.  Are you removing it just to squeeze out a bit more performance, or is it something more?  Also, will one of you be writing a blog post about it? ;P

Comment: @BlueRaja - it's becoming more and more of a PITA, it's use has been reduced due to (not at all insignificant) performance differences...but we have to make some major code shifts coming up that'll be painful, more so (maybe impossible) with LINQ in our data layer.  If I find the time I'll try and write up our major issues with it, with a new babby my blog time has been nada, that should change a bit over the next month or so.