# Comments not being indexed in network profiles (again)

Tags: bug, comments, stackexchange.com, network-profile

[This Academia comment](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/139941/are-results-that-are-derived-simply-by-using-more-computational-power-publishabl#comment372029_139941) still has not shown up on [my network profile's list of comments](https://stackexchange.com/users/85546/blueraja-danny-pflughoeft?tab=activity). The [last time this happened](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/138697/why-are-my-comments-no-longer-showing-up-on-my-stack-exchange-profile) (2012), some script needed to be run or something.

Comment: Well the index is working now. The comment was only posted 18 minutes ago.

Comment: @Mari-LouA It says it was posted yesterday (2019-11-14 01:37:26Z) for me.

Comment: @DanielFischer right you are, the network profile page has a much different date of time.

Comment: Interesting, @Mari-LouA, I don't see it on the network profile at all.

Comment: If users would actually copy the comments and link them probably, it would help instead of writing "this" and "here" and "probably". It's all a bit confusing, at least for me, so I'm bowing out before I make an even greater fool of myself.

Comment: When in doubt, blame caching.